solana devnet subscribe spl token program, can't get event for my own token?
On devnet, I subscribe token program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA, and try to get events for USDC token (4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU) events.
But I can't get any events for the token.
The same program can subscribe mainnet's usdt event correctly.
So, does devnet only push event for specific tokens ?

(Ok, I found why this happen)
I subscribed multiple addresses, and try receive events in a nested loop.
But the receive operation is blocking, this cause only 1 address can receive at a time, other addresses are blocked.
The solution is to use 1 thread (or lightweight routines, e.g goroutine) for each subscription.
